# New line character added to HTML attribute via jQuery doesn't work for CSS generated content

Tags: css, attributes

If I write my new line character `&#xa;` directly as HTML attribute, then it can work for CSS generated content. For example:

```css
div::after {
    content: attr(data-generated-content);
    white-space: pre;
    }
```

```html
<div data-generated-content="First line&#xa;Second line"></div>
```

However, if the new line character was added via jQuery, then it doesn't work. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div').attr('data-generated-content', 'First line&#xa;Second line');
});
```

```css
div::after {
    content: attr(data-generated-content);
    white-space: pre;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Here is a [complete demo](http://jsfiddle.net/em1mLbbh/) on jsFiddle.

How do I make the new line character added via jQuery work for CSS generated content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript `\n` instead, here is a demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div').attr('data-generated-content', 'First line\nSecond line');
});
```

```css
div::after {
    content: attr(data-generated-content);
    white-space: pre;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: @IanY. i'm glad i could help